# PlatformException(-11819, Cannot Complete Action, null, null)) after playing for few minutes :Flutter

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

My app is having different channels and different m3u8 urls (non ending music stream) for the player.I am using `HlsAudioSource` to set the m3u8 url and it is working fine for few minutes.after the player is stopped and I am getting exception `PlatformException(-11819, Cannot Complete Action, null, null))` inside the playbackState stream.

My audioHandler code is as follows.

```
Future<AudioHandler> initAudioService() async {
  return await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => MyAudioHandler(),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'io.test.testMusic',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'testMusic',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
      androidStopForegroundOnPause: true,
    ),
  );
}

class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler {
  final AudioPlayer _player = AudioPlayer();

  MyAudioHandler() {
    _player.playbackEventStream.map(_transformEvent).pipe(playbackState);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> playFromUri(Uri uri, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) async {
    mediaItem.add(MediaItem(id: uri.toString(), title: 'MoodStream'));
    print('url=====${uri.toString()}');
    try {
      _player.setAudioSource(
        HlsAudioSource(uri
            // Uri.parse(
            //   'https://demo.unified-streaming.com/k8s/features/stable/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/.m3u8',
            // ),
            ),
      );
    } on PlayerException catch (e) {
      print('exception==$e');
      return;
    }

    return; //_player.playing ? _player.pause() : _player.play();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> click([MediaButton button = MediaButton.media]) async {
    print('button===${button}');
    switch (button) {
      case MediaButton.media:
        {
          if (playbackState.valueOrNull?.playing == true) {
            await _player.pause();
          } else {
            await _player.play();
          }
          break;
        }
      case MediaButton.next:
      // TODO: Handle this case.
      case MediaButton.previous:
      // TODO: Handle this case.
    }
    return super.click(button);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() async {
    await _player.play();
    return super.play();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> pause() async {
    await _player.pause();
    return super.pause();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> stop() async {
    await _player.stop();
    return super.stop();
  }

  PlaybackState _transformEvent(PlaybackEvent event) {
    return PlaybackState(
        controls: [
          // MediaControl.rewind,
          if (_player.playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
          //MediaControl.stop,
          // MediaControl.fastForward,
        ],
        // systemActions: const {
        //   MediaAction.seek,
        //   MediaAction.seekForward,
        //   MediaAction.seekBackward,
        // },
        androidCompactActionIndices: const [
          0,
          1,
          3
        ],
        processingState: const {
          ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
          ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
          ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
          ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
          ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
        }[_player.processingState]!,
        playing: _player.playing,
        updatePosition: _player.position,
        bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
        speed: _player.speed,
        queueIndex: event.currentIndex,
        errorMessage: 'error');
  }
}
```

playerHandler in bloc is

```
initPlayerHandler(Uri playerUri) async {
    bool isValid = await isValidPlaylist();
    if (isValid) {
      try {
        if (homeBloc.state.selectedRoom != null) {
          await playerHandler.playFromUri(playerUri);
          if (state.isPlaying) {
            _resumePlay();
          }
          _subscribeToStream();
        }
      } on PlayerException catch (e) {
        print('set player error====$e');
        GlobalSnackBar.show('Error in playlist content');
        emit(state.copyWith(
            playbackStatus: PlaybackStatus.error, isPlaying: false));
        //setPlayer(isFromException: true);
      }
    } else {
      GlobalSnackBar.show('This room does\'t has any playlist.');
    }
  }
```

playbackState listnener is

```
playerHandler.playbackState.listen(
      (event) async {
        if (event.processingState == AudioProcessingState.buffering) {
          /// bufferring
          emit(state.copyWith(playbackStatus: PlaybackStatus.buffering));
        }
        if (event.processingState == AudioProcessingState.ready) {
          emit(state.copyWith(playbackStatus: PlaybackStatus.playing));
        }

        if (event.playing) {
          if (event.processingState == AudioProcessingState.completed) {
            await setPlayer();
          } else {
            if (event.processingState == AudioProcessingState.idle) {
            } else if (event.processingState == AudioProcessingState.ready) {
              if (state.isPlaying) {
                return;
              }
              emit(state.copyWith(
                  playbackStatus: PlaybackStatus.playing, isPlaying: true));
              if (state.isPlaying) {
                _resumePlay();
              }
            }
          }
        } 
      },
      onError: (e) async {
        print('_subscribeToStream==onError==$e');
        GlobalSnackBar.show(e.message);
        emit(state.copyWith(
            playbackStatus: PlaybackStatus.playing, isPlaying: false));
      },
      onDone: () async {
        await setPlayer();
      },
    );
```

other player functions are

```
Future<void> _stopPlayer() async {
    try {
    
      await playerHandler.stop();
      return Future<void>.value();
    } catch (e) {
      print('player error _stopPlayer====$e');
      Future<void>.value();
    }
  }

  _resumePlay() async {
    try {
      await playerHandler.play();
      _onPlayStausChange(3);
    } catch (e) {
      print('player error _resumePlay====$e');
      emit(state.copyWith(
          playbackStatus: PlaybackStatus.error, isPlaying: false));
      GlobalSnackBar.show('Player content exception');
    }
  }

  _pausePlay() async {
    try {
      await playerHandler.pause();
      _onPlayStausChange(1);
      emit(state.copyWith(
          playbackStatus: PlaybackStatus.paused, isPlaying: false));
    } catch (e) {
      print('player error _pausePlay====$e');
      emit(state.copyWith(
          playbackStatus: PlaybackStatus.error, isPlaying: false));
    }
  }
```

flutter doctor is given below

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.9, on macOS 14.1 23B74 darwin-arm64, locale en-AE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.0)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

From android device ,when the player stops ,I could able to get the player state as bufferring and the logs ,but no exceptions or errors.

```
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 5497): bufferpool2 0xb4000073b9599e28 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 18216/18221 (recycle/alloc) - 5/36438 (fetch/transfer)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 5497): bufferpool2 0xb4000073b9599e28 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 4(32768 size) used buffers - 18246/18251 (recycle/alloc) - 5/36492 (fetch/transfer)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 5497): evictor expired: 1, evicted: 1
D/TrafficStats( 5497): tagSocket(171) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```